# Discriminate function and object types based on an enum member

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

I'm trying to get narrowed types in TypeScript when working with index signatures and union types without discriminating them directly, e.g. using a switch case statement.

The code below throws an error when calling the doubleFn variable with the shape, although at runtime the shape is correctly returned as a circle, the doubleFn is inferred as the function for doubling the radius and calling it works as well.

Is it possible to narrow the type of doubleFn so that it understands that it is the matching pair to the given shape?

[Link to TypeScript playground with the same code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=47&pc=23#code/KYOwrgtgBAygFgQwA7AM5QN4FgBQUoDCAlgE4DGANsADS74wCOYCJNuAvrrkSAC7AkAZgjLBYiFAAUSAexQleRNJjpQA2vGRoAdMXJUAugC4VefFBIIAJkTCoT4CACMBAblXt3ZjRJ2NmrMam5lBUIADmvHAOkC4kXvieHFw4vACeKFAAYmAgZIoyIKgAKhliALzB6gDWwGlQPOJaqEEAFAgmmlKy8opoarVpBgCUUOUAfE3dcgJ9qAN1Bl5JOLhkhai8UFYyYE5UOXkFRSaH%20UQbpZmV2N5dOnqUwG1kpE-ScvZTwB%209SvP3VC6N6GUYTKCtW4hSw2OwmV76H49IEw2zoABUUAATLQzOxhrj8D5mtp-CxniZWqgmOTfl97r9Zv9iSggWTAmDJpDVPgwpFolBqQEkZ9tHyolBMTiPASOF5uHwBMJRIQQWIoVB0ihOr4gY8qAkoEhkTqtIyFMzAcDEUtkqscDx%20EIRGJ2erVFrgKbWaSaaxDcbPt6RX9%20la3bacJx7Z7vmNVYioAAfWB%204DynCCXLnQpQcLAXj3VrDYNVVi8MAkECYTVlYN6tXUI0mmuouFQACsUHY3eWKXWRS2qF88fzhd8xa8A82212%202AWWrlR2ewO2eO82HWm0nsjuBX88XVN82kDSFQw1cQA)

```
enum Shapes {
  Circle,
  Square,
}

interface ShapeProperties {
  [Shapes.Circle]: {
    radius: number;
  };
  [Shapes.Square]: {
    length: number;
  };
}

type FunctionsType = {
  [key in Shapes]: (a: ShapeProperties[key]) => ShapeProperties[key];
};

const doubleFunctions: FunctionsType = {
  [Shapes.Circle]: (circleProps: ShapeProperties[Shapes.Circle]) => ({
    radius: circleProps.radius * 2,
  }),
  [Shapes.Square]: (squareProps: ShapeProperties[Shapes.Square]) => ({
    length: squareProps.length * 2,
  }),
};

interface Circle {
  type: Shapes.Circle;
  props: ShapeProperties[Shapes.Circle];
}

interface Square {
  type: Shapes.Square;
  props: ShapeProperties[Shapes.Square];
}

type Shape = Circle | Square;

function getShape(): Shape {
  return { type: Shapes.Circle, props: { radius: 5 } };
}

const shape = getShape();
const doubleFn = doubleFunctions[shape.type];

doubleFn(shape.props);
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is closely related to what I've been calling "correlated records" (see [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)); the compiler doesn't really know how to track correlations between different union-typed values, so it assumes they are independent and that gives errors in cases like this.

In this specific case, you have `doubleFun` and `shape.props`, and the compiler sees each of them as being union-typed:

```
const doubleFn = doubleFunctions[shape.type];
/* const doubleFn: 
  ((a: {radius: number;}) => {radius: number;}) | 
  ((a: {length: number;}) => {length: number;}) 
*/

const props = shape.props;
/* const props: {radius: number;} | {length: number;} */
```

Those types aren't *incorrect*, but they are *insufficient* for the compiler to realize that it is safe to call `doubleFn(props)`:

```
doubleFn(props); // error!
```

The compiler is complaining that maybe `doubleFn` will turn out to be the square-processing-function while `props` will be circle-properties... or vice versa.  That would indeed be an error at runtime.  The *correlation* between `doubleFn` and `props` is not represented in the type system.

---

There's no great way to deal with this in TypeScript for now.  You can, as you noted, use a switch/case or other conditional code to prompt the compiler to use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis) and see that in each case, the call is safe.  But that's redundant.

The only other direct solution right now is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler that you've made sure what you're doing is safe.  This is risky because you are taking the responsibility of verifying type safety upon yourself.  So if you're going to use type assertions, it's often best to confine them to a small bit of code that you reuse elsewhere:

```
const toShapeFunction = (f: FunctionsType) => <S extends Shape>(s: S) =>
  (f[s.type] as (s: S['props']) => S['props'])(s.props);
```

The function `toShapeFunction()` converts an argument of type `FunctionsType` to a function that operates on any `Shape` and produces the appropriate properties type output.  The type assertion is us telling the compiler: "`f[s.type]` will accept a value of the type of `s.props` and produce a value of the same type".  That compiles without error.  Then you can use `toShapeFunction()` without worry:

```
const doubleFunction = toShapeFunction(doubleFunctions);

const newSh = doubleFunction(shape); // okay

const ci: Circle = {
  type: Shapes.Circle,
  props: { radius: 10 }
}
const newCi = doubleFunction(ci);
console.log(newCi.radius); // 20

const sq: Square = {
  type: Shapes.Square,
  props: { length: 35 }
}
const newSq = doubleFunction(sq);
console.log(newSq.length); // 70
```

Looks good.

---

So that's the situation.  I had at one point suggested some way to make dealing with correlated values less painful (see [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051)) but it didn't really get any traction.  So I'd suggest for now that you refactor the code enough so that the number of type assertions necessary is small enough to be manageable.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAygFgQwA7AM5QN4FgBQUoDCAlgE4DGANsADS74wCOYCJNuAvrrkSAC7AkAZgjLBYiFAAUSAexQleRNJjpQA2vGRoAdMXJUAugC4VefFBIIAJkTCoT4CACMBAblXt3ZjRJ2NmrMam5lBUIADmvHAOkC4kXvieHFw4vACeKFAAYmAgZIoyIKgAKhliALzB6gDSUDziWqhBABQIJppSsvKKaGrVBgCUUOUAfA2dcgI9qH0GXkk4Kbhkhai8UFYyYE5UOXkFRSZ7+USrpZmV2N4dOnqUwC1kpPfScvbjwK-dSjM3qLrPQxDUZQZpXEKWGx2ExPfSfLr-SG2dAAKigACZaGZ2AMsfgfI1tP4WA8TM1UEwSV93jcvlMfgSUP9iYFgWMwap8GFItEoBSAvC3tpuVEoGjMR5cRwvNw+AJhKJCICxOCoOkUO1fP87lQElAkAjNVo6QoGX8AXC5slFjgePwhCIxCyVap1cAjUyiZTWHqDW8PYLvr1zc6rThODa3R9hkq4VAAD6wb3AGU4QS5E6FKDhYC8G7NAYBqqsXhgEggTBqsoB7XK6j6w2VpHQqAAVig7A78xSKyK61QvhjObzvgLXl7aw2Wx2wCyFcqm22uwzBxmA602jdYYA9GiJ+tFzO5yZVM1WiYMM33o44q4ccMxpfrMiYs43PfE6fz5gRbyb++2R-UAeVfW971wFFt2WVZ1j9JB0EqdcUG0ODUC8XcoH3Bt-UwK9QPfBMgIiKJ8PiTtINwQ9dhAZpUIGVwoG3bcoAEWQSAAQiWG1oL7NUZBuY4DhjZpBCOFdTiKc5gEAgAeGAWIAD34EArHQG4RnJdo2VPQQ1H+LcoAQdBNNgNQAHJULMwYH1MiyESsgZyRQhF6J7GCpyXWdxKzSpeH43xBIk5oqK8-YJNQVybSwkBgAAd3gGMQsCwpyV8ejGOYmQAGsEDSNzeKeEwdQqKo3RrC17jxbD4IvCxnxbABGAAGDtrWiuLiES6dlzClKnkiicZCoYUZHCZoYti4htCvdKmIxJr8snCl2mTGNVTKj5mWTKrUNq38TAAZnbCMI3a+KGC6zzkpoikBtWIbgBGsaJsYYVgKiWbmIAdgW7ibSgLigA)